# Hive SerDe returns error with JSON tweets Flume

Tags: json, hadoop, twitter, hive, hive-serde

I am collecting twitter stream data using Flume and storing it in JSON format in HDFS. I am trying to use Hive SerDe to put this twitter data into Hive table but I am getting a very frustrating error.

```
hive> ADD JAR file:////home/ubuntu/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
Added [file:////home/ubuntu/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar] to class path
Added resources: [file:////home/ubuntu/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar]
hive>  CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweet (
    >    id BIGINT,
    >    created_at STRING,
    >    source STRING,
    >    favorited BOOLEAN,
    >    text STRING,
    >    in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
    >  ) 
    > 
    >  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
    >  LOCATION '/user/ubuntu/twitter/';
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is datehour coming from?Leave out the PARTITIONED BY (datehour INT)

Comment: Can you please show a sample of events?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, however, I found a work around to solve the problem:

1. `create table tweets(tweet string);`
2. `load data inpath 'home/hduser/test.json' into table tweets;`

The only difference now you will need to use, `get_json_object()` to use the data.

Like below:

```
select get_json_object(tweet,'$.text') as tweet_text, get_json_object(tweet,'$.created_at') as created_at  from tweets;
```

[Reference](https://www.guru99.com/data-extraction-hive.html)